# Why is thing[:][0] equal to thing[0][:]?

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to make a very simple check in my Pyhton script where I have a 6000 columns but only 3 rows of data in multiple arrays.

In order to get some overview of what my script is doing I would like to add some checks at certain points in the script which prints a few columns of my arrays to my linux terminal window and compare it with hand calculations to ensure I am not making an error anywhere.

If I print: `print(NH3flux[0][0])` or `print(NH3flux[1][0])` i get the correct data.

If I do a `print(NH3flux[0][:])` i get my entire first row (Or column if you prefer)

The Problem: If I do a `print(NH3flux[:][0])` i get the exact same result as `print(NH3flux[0][:])` which confuses me as I thought I understood arrays in Python?

If I replace my `:` with numbers `0`, `1` or `2` I get the correct data and `3` crashes the execution and for some reason `:` sign does not work.

What am I failing to understand?

Edit:
Please note that the numbers may be in string form as they are read from a database and thus has not been converted yet. What format the object has is hopefully not the issue here.

```
print(NH3flux[0][0]) returns 0.00000

print(NH3flux[1][0]) returns 0.00001

print(NH3flux[2][0]) returns 0.00013

print(NH3flux[3][0]) returns list index out of range as expected

print(NH3flux[0][:]) returns '0.00000', '0.00000', '0.00003', '0.00002'
```

, ... etc

Comment: please a) add the output of each of the `print` statements that you provided. b) explain exactly how the results you got differed from what you thought you would get c) include the errors you get when you use `3` and `:`

Comment: Those are nested lists. They don't index that way but NumPy's arrays do. If  NH3flux was such an object then `NH3flux[:, 0]` would be the first column if `NH3flux[0, :]` is the first row (if not flip row and column).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`thing[:]` returns a copy of `thing`*.

`NH3flux[:][0]` gives you *the same object* as `NH3flux[0]`, and `NH3flux[0][:]` gives you *a copy* of `NH3flux[0]`.

The reason `NH3flux[:][0]` looks the same as `NH3flux[0][:]` is because an object looks the same as its copy when you `print` it*.

* *Usually; for `list`'s and `tuple`'s, and most other things that want to follow the convention.*

Answer (score 1):

```
NH3flux[:]
```

selects all the columns (assuming your matrix is a list of lists); `NH3flux[:][0]` the first one of these - your first row.

Answer (score 0):

`print(NH3flux[0][:])` selects the first subelement/row and makes a shallow copy, `print(NH3flux[:][0])` makes a shallow copy of the whole list and selects the first row from the list so you are always accessing the first subelement/row in the list.

```
In [7]: l = [[1,2],[2,3]]
In [8]: l[0] # first element
Out[8]: [1, 2]  
In [9]: l[:] # whole list
Out[9]: [[1, 2], [2, 3]]
In [10]: l[0][:] # copy of first row
Out[10]: [1, 2]    
In [11]: l[:][0] # shallow copy of whole list and getting first row
Out[11]: [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure as to what data you are using so i can only assume. But say you had something like:
val = [1,2], print(val[:]) 
That would give you everything in that list, now if you did print(val[:][1]) that would give you only number 2 because the first [:] is giving you everything then [1] is giving you the second item in the list. 
If you did a list like val = [1,2,[3,4]]
 then a print of print(val[2][:]) that would give you 3,4. It sounds like  your trying to print something out of range of what is in your data type but without knowing what data your are trying to parse per say im guessing.